# Auto Age Calculation Field View In Html Form

Tags: view, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to auto calculate the field for age in my asp.net mvc form and post it to the form. I am using datetimepicker to derive the date of birth. Does anyone know how to calculate it just by using the date of birth and post it straight to the forms? Here is my view:

```
 <script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // DateA
        $('#JSDateA')
            .datetimepicker({ format: 'YYYY-MM-DD' });


<form asp-controller="Admin" asp-action="Edit"
      method="post">

    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="offset-sm-2 col-sm-5 ">
            Update User
        </div>
    </div>




  

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" asp-for="Dob">Birth Date :</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <input asp-for="Dob" asp-format="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"
                   class="form-control" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" />
        </div>
        @{
            // TODO: L09 Task 4d - Validation Message for Dob
        }
    </div>

    
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="Age">Age :</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <input type="text" id="age" asp-for="Age" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        
    </div>





    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="offset-sm-2 col-sm-6">
            <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </div>

    @if (ViewData["Message"] != null)
    {
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="offset-sm-2 col-sm-6">
                <div class="alert alert-@ViewData["MsgType"]">
                    @Html.Raw(ViewData["Message"])
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate age using js. By setting change event, calculate date and put it to age text field. Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#txtDOB").change(function(){
       var dob = $("#txtDOB").val();
    
       if(dob != null || dob != ""){
          $("#age").val(getAge(dob));
       }
  });
  
  function getAge(birth) {
    ageMS = Date.parse(Date()) - Date.parse(birth);
    age = new Date();
    age.setTime(ageMS);
    ageYear = age.getFullYear() - 1970;

    return ageYear;
   }
});
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/4f1o3jpc/7/) is a example fiddle for you.

Comment: How do I call it in my form field for age? Do I just insert the id = age? @Fawad Hussain

Comment: You should use age field same as you're using date of birth field. Bind it with model property named age. Declare age property in your binding model to be able to post age.

Answer (score 0):

Before resolve your issue,you need know the following things:

1.If `Dob` in your model is type of `DateTime`,it will generate `<input type="date">`,you need set the html `type="text"`,otherwise you will have two datepicker,one belongs to jquery ui,the other belongs to the default html5 datepicker.

2.jquery set input text value by using `val()`.

3.You do not have any html element which has `id="JSDateA"`,so what you did will never work.

Working Demo:

Model:

```
public class TestVM
{
    public DateTime Dob { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

}
```

View:

```
<form asp-controller="Admin" asp-action="Edit"
      method="post">

    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="offset-sm-2 col-sm-5 ">
            Update User
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" asp-for="Dob">Birth Date :</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <input asp-for="Dob" asp-format="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"
                   class="form-control" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" type="text" />
                                                           @*add type="text"*@
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="Age">Age :</label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <input type="text" id="age" asp-for="Age" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="offset-sm-2 col-sm-6">
                <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
        @if (ViewData["Message"] != null)
        {
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="offset-sm-2 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="alert alert-@ViewData["MsgType"]">
                        @Html.Raw(ViewData["Message"])
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</form>
```

The first way,you could write js like below(by using **[jquery UI Datepicker Widget](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/)**):

```
@section Scripts{
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#Dob')
                .datepicker({   
                    format: 'yyyy-MM-DD',
                    maxDate: '+0d',
                    yearRange: '1950:2021',
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    onSelect: function (value, ui) {
                        var today = new Date(),
                            dob = new Date(value),
                            age = new Date(today - dob).getFullYear() - 1970;

                        $('#age').val(age); 
                    }
                });
        })

    </script>
}
```

Result:

[image]

The second way,you could write js like below(by using **bootstrap-datetimepicker**):

```
@section Scripts
{
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#Dob').datetimepicker();
            $('#Dob').on('dp.change', function (e) {
                var value = e.date.format(e.date._f);
                var today = new Date(),
                    dob = new Date(value),
                    age = new Date(today - dob).getFullYear() - 1970;

                $('#age').val(age);
            })
        });
    </script>
}
```

Result2:

[image]